# Showing Extended SplashScreen Removed my Back Button C# UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, splash-screen, back-button

I have added the BackButton to my UWP App using this article: http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/jprosise/handling-the-back-button-in-windows-10-uwp-apps then I wanted to add an ExtendedSplashScreen to my App. So I used this article: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/020f8f/universal-windows-platform-and-extended-splash-screen/

But when I added my ExtendedSplashScreen the BackButton disappeared from the Pages I'm opening after the MainPage. I know it is related to what I'm calling rootframe, but I can't figure out what I should change. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that in `DismissExtendedSplash` method, the author create a new `rootFrame` and set it as `Window.Current.Content`. This override the `rootFrame` created in App.xaml.cs, so the code for handling the Back Button won't work. To fix this issue, you can just use `Window.Current.Content as Frame` in `DismissExtendedSplash` method to get the `rootFrame` like following:

```
private async void DismissExtendedSplash()
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
    // set your desired delay
    //rootFrame = new Frame();
    //MainPage mainPage = new MainPage();
    //rootFrame.Content = mainPage;
    //Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
    //rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage)); // call MainPage
    ((Window.Current.Content) as Frame).Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Code from the `DismissExtendedSplash` method overrides frame and the `OnNavigated` event.

You can use a little trick. In App.xaml.cs, make `rootFrame` a global variable:

```
public static Frame rootFrame;
```

And also add:

```
public static new App Current
{
   get { return Application.Current as App; }
}
```

Now your `DismissExtendedSplash` could be like:

```
async void DismissExtendedSplash()
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)); // set your desired delay  
    App.rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
}
```